# replacing the same pattern in a string with new value each time

Tags: r, string

One string with 25 `xy` as patterns and a 25 long vector that should replace those 25 xy.

This is not for prgramming or anything complicated, I just wish to get a result, which I can copy and then paste into a forum that uses this BBcode inside the string to make a colorful line.

```
string <- "[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]__[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]" 

colrs <- c( "08070D", "100F1A", "191627", "211E34", "292541", "312D4E", "39345B", "413C68", "4A4375", "524A82", "5A528E", "62599B", "6C64A6", "7971AE", "827BB3", "8C85B9", "958FBF", "9F99C4", "A9A3CA", "B2AED0", "BCB8D6", "C5C2DC", "CFCCE2", "D9D6E8", "E2E0ED")
```

and want this as a result

```
[COLOR="#08070D"]_[COLOR="#100F1A"]_[COLOR="#191627"]_[COLOR="#211E34"]_[COLOR="#292541"]_[COLOR="#312D4E"]_[COLOR="#39345B"]_[COLOR="#413C68"]_[COLOR="#4A4375"]_[COLOR="#524A82"]_[COLOR="#5A528E"]_[COLOR="#62599B"]_[COLOR="#6C64A6"]_[COLOR="#7971AE"]_[COLOR="#827BB3"]_[COLOR="#8C85B9"]_[COLOR="#958FBF"]_[COLOR="#9F99C4"]_[COLOR="#A9A3CA"]_[COLOR="#B2AED0"]_[COLOR="#BCB8D6"]_[COLOR="#C5C2DC"]_[COLOR="#CFCCE2"]_[COLOR="#D9D6E8"]_[COLOR="#E2E0ED"]__[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]
```

Comment: From where do you get the hex code to replace `#xy`  in the `string` ?

Comment: What I don't follow with your initial problem is that your initial string has 14 instances of `#xy` but your final output has 25 instances of hex codes.

Comment: I guess I copy and pasted the wrong part of what I tried before, sry about that, but that part is not important at all. The core is still trying to replace stuff like in the edit.
who wouldve thought that what i believed to be a simple question ends up being such a problem

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT #2**:
An easy solution to the new data problem is this:

```
library(stringr)
string0 <- unlist(str_split(gsub('"', "", string), "__?"))
str_c(str_replace(string0,'xy', colrs), collapse = "_")
[1] "[COLOR=#08070D]_[COLOR=#100F1A]_[COLOR=#191627]_[COLOR=#211E34]_[COLOR=#292541]_[COLOR=#312D4E]_[COLOR=#39345B]_[COLOR=#413C68]_[COLOR=#4A4375]_[COLOR=#524A82]_[COLOR=#5A528E]_[COLOR=#62599B]_[COLOR=#6C64A6]_[COLOR=#7971AE]_[COLOR=#827BB3]_[COLOR=#8C85B9]_[COLOR=#958FBF]_[COLOR=#9F99C4]_[COLOR=#A9A3CA]_[COLOR=#B2AED0]_[COLOR=#BCB8D6]_[COLOR=#C5C2DC]_[COLOR=#CFCCE2]_[COLOR=#D9D6E8]_[COLOR=#E2E0ED]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]"
```

**EDIT**:

Given this data:

```
string <- "AxyBxyCxyDxyExy"
vector <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

and this desired result:

```
"A1B2C3D4E5"
```

you can do this:

```
library(stringr)
```

First, we extract the character that's before `xy` using `str_extract_all`:

```
string0 <- unlist(str_extract_all(string, ".(?=xy)"))
```

Next we do two things: a) we replace the lone character with itself (`\\1`) AND the `vector` value, and b) we collapse the separate strings into one large string using `str_c`:

```
str_c(str_replace(string0, "(.)$", str_c("\\1", vector)), collapse = "")
[1] "A1B2C3D4E5"
```

Comment: thank you! but when I do it i get this message

Warning message:
In sub("xy", colrs, string0) :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: and I just noticed that the result for string_new only uses one hexcode,

Comment: It depends on what your vector with the color codes looks like. Can you post a sample of it? If it does not look like this one `colrs <- c("#08070D","#100F1A","#191627","#211E34","#292541")`then the code cannot work...

Comment: a sample is not needed right now, because the message appears when i literally just copy and paste the code you gave me. What could be the reason?

Comment: sorry without more data from you I can't pass any judgement and cannot help you

Comment: I made an edit to the question and hope it is clearer what I actually want

Comment: Have edited answer to fit new data. The regex will probably need adjusting to your actual data...

Answer (score 0):

I have completely revised my answer given that you removed the previous iteration of your code example. Here's the revised solution:

```
string <- '[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]_[COLOR="#xy"]__[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]'    
colrs <- c("08070D", "100F1A", "191627", "211E34", "292541", "312D4E", "39345B", "413C68", "4A4375", "524A82", "5A528E", "62599B", "6C64A6", "7971AE", "827BB3", "8C85B9", "958FBF", "9F99C4", "A9A3CA", "B2AED0", "BCB8D6", "C5C2DC", "CFCCE2", "D9D6E8", "E2E0ED") 

library(stringr)
string0 <- string |>
  str_split("xy") |>
  unlist()

string0[seq_along(colrs)] |> 
  str_c(colrs, collapse = "") |> 
  str_c(string0[length(colrs)+1])
[1] "[COLOR=\"#08070D\"]_[COLOR=\"#100F1A\"]_[COLOR=\"#191627\"]_[COLOR=\"#211E34\"]_[COLOR=\"#292541\"]_[COLOR=\"#312D4E\"]_[COLOR=\"#39345B\"]_[COLOR=\"#413C68\"]_[COLOR=\"#4A4375\"]_[COLOR=\"#524A82\"]_[COLOR=\"#5A528E\"]_[COLOR=\"#62599B\"]_[COLOR=\"#6C64A6\"]_[COLOR=\"#7971AE\"]_[COLOR=\"#827BB3\"]_[COLOR=\"#8C85B9\"]_[COLOR=\"#958FBF\"]_[COLOR=\"#9F99C4\"]_[COLOR=\"#A9A3CA\"]_[COLOR=\"#B2AED0\"]_[COLOR=\"#BCB8D6\"]_[COLOR=\"#C5C2DC\"]_[COLOR=\"#CFCCE2\"]_[COLOR=\"#D9D6E8\"]_[COLOR=\"#E2E0ED\"]__[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]_[/color]"
```

Comment: thank you, we are getting closer to what I wanted.
I rewrote my question more clearly (I hope) this time with right amount of stuff this time (again I hope)